# Shellscript: return multiple values for cut function

Tags: shell, sh

I'm using cut function for getting all sub strings. For example: I have a string named "v1.2.3". I want assign 1 to major. 2 to minor and 3 to bug (remove first character is always v)

For example below:

```
  major=$(echo $tag | cut -d'.' -f1)
  minor=$(echo $tag | cut -d'.' -f2)
  bug=$(echo $tag | cut -d'.' -f3)
  echo "$major $minor $bug"
```

This script expands on 3 lines. My question is: how can I return all `f1` `f2` and `f3` in one call and assign back to `major` `minor` and `bug` at same time.

I also try to use regular expression. for example: `v1.2.3` will be split to 1,2 and 3 respectively but it seems not work.

```
  re="^v(.*).(.*).(.*)$"
  [[ $tag =~ $re ]] && major="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" && minor="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" && patch="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  echo $major
  echo $minor
  echo $patch
```

thanks.

Comment: @tripleee thanks. I have updated my question for using regular expression. Please take a look.

Comment: Your regex is nondeterministic.  If you want to split on literal dots, `IFS='.'` as suggested in the suggested duplicate.  (FWIW the regular expression to match a literal dot is `\.` or equivalently `[.]`.)  To trim a leading prefix, `${tag#v}` produces the value of `tag` with any leading `v` removed.

Comment: @tripleee thanks. but using this method. I will lost some information about $2 $3 that I need in other place. How can I fix this

Comment: @TrầnKimDự: Check out my answer below.

Comment: Please flag as duplicate and post your answers to the nominated duplicate instead if the method you want to propose is not already documented there.

Comment: @tripleee: my bad! didn't wanted to exactly duplicate it, as it involved a minor substitution to be done. Will share the documentation link right-away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in pure `bash` string-manipulation See [shell-parameter-expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for various techniques.

```
$ IFS="." read -r major minor bug <<< "v1.2.3" # read the strings to variables
$ major="${major/v/}"                          # removing the character 'v' from major
$ printf "%s %s %s\n" "$major" "$minor" "$bug" # printing the individual variables
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I've recently learned of "read". Goes a little like this:

```
#set field separator to match your delimiter
ifsOld=$IFS
IFS='.'

read major minor bug <<<$(echo $tag | cut -d'.' -f 1,2,3)

IFS=$ifsOld
```

eg:

```
$ IFS='.'
$ read major minor bug <<<$(echo 127.1.2.123 | cut -d'.' -f 1,2,3)
$ echo $major $minor $bug
127 1 2
$
```

Comment: as your code provide me. major will be "127 1 2" but both minor and bug will be empty

Comment: I have updated my question. In sort, I want to break 1/2/3 to each variable.

Comment: I didn't get that. 
eg, if I instead used `echo $bug $minor $major` It would return `2 1 127`
Edit: but on 2 different linux flavours, it only works on one of them :(